# Portable signed right shift

Tags: c

I would like to [perform a right shift on a negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1857928). According to the linked answers, performing a right shift on a negative number is implementation-defined, because the sign bit may or may not be maintained. Here's my solution to this.

```c
int n = -18;
printf("%d %d\n", n&0xF, ~((~n)>>4));
// Filler
```

I reasoning is that if I `not` the value to perform the shift then `not` it back, it won't matter whether the sign bit is shifted or not. However I'm still unsure if this fully solves the problem. Suggestions?

Comment: How do you form an opinion whether a *procedure* is a *solution*? Suggestion: Try defining and automating a *test*. Finding that impossible, the *problem definition* may be insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no, your approach does not work if the implementation's right-shift is zero-filling and `n` is positive.

Here's my test program: https://godbolt.org/z/WxsjnW

```
int SAR(int n, int sh) {
    return n >> sh;  // sign-filling (arithmetic) "shift right"
}

int SHR(int n, int sh) {
    return (unsigned)n >> sh;  // zero-filling (logical) "shift right"
}

int main() {
    int n = -18;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", SAR(n, 4), ~SAR(~n, 4), ~SHR(~n, 4));
    n = 18;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", SAR(n, 4), ~SAR(~n, 4), ~SHR(~n, 4));
}
```

In practice you can rely on right-shift to do the sign-filling thing, because we already have a way to get the zero-filling thing (just cast to unsigned first). But if you really really want a sign-propagating right-shift, perhaps consider reusing integer division, or adding the sign bits back manually after the shift? https://godbolt.org/z/xsonbK

```
int SAR(int n, int sh)
{
    int mask = -(n < 0) * (1 << sh);
    return ((unsigned)n >> sh) | mask;
}
```

I bet Google knows even cleverer tricks.

Comment: `return n < 0 ? ~((~(unsigned)n) >> sh) : n >> sh;`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work though, I noticed that `mask` adds a lot more than the missing bits. It should be `(n < 0)*(~((~0u)>>sh))`. What's happening is your mask is all 1 except for the first `sh` least significant bits. It should be only the first `sh` _most_ significant bits are 1 and the rest are 0. `(~0u)` is `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: Or, since my mask would be compile time constant (except for the < 0 check), I could just define it as `(n < 0)*0xF0000000`. Also, instead of `(n < 0)*`, it could be `(-(n < 0))&`.

Comment: Also, how about `return ((unsigned)n >> 4)|((-(n < 0)) << 28);`?

Comment: After some testing, using `(n>>31)` seems to be faster than `(n < 0)`

Comment: Yes, but if you know that `(n>>31)` is equivalent to `(n < 0)` for signed `n`, then your original issue is already solved — you know that the built-in signed shift operator is sign-extending. :)

Comment: `(n>>31)` was wrong, I meant `((unsigned)n>>31)`

Comment: Note:, with 32-bit `int`, `1 << sh` is UB when `sh==31`.  Consider `1u << sh`.   `int mask` as `unsigned mask` makes more sense.

Comment: `return n >> sh;  // sign-filling (arithmetic) "shift right"` relies on implementation-defined behavior: "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right."  C17dr § 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check at preprocess time if shifts are 0 filling or sign filling, because if they are in fact sign filling, then the simple `>>4` works and using a more complex workaround is only wasting processor power, so only use it where it's needed, and let the preprocessor take care of that for you

```
#if ((-1)>>1) < 0 // Check if rightshift on negative number is sign filling or 0 filling
#   define RSHIFT4(N) ((N)>>4)
#else
#   define RSHIFT4(N) (((N)>>4)|((-((unsigned int)(N)>>0x1F))<<0x1C))
#endif
```

However, to be portable, you should replace `0x1F` and `0x1C` with `(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)-1` and `(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)-4` respectively, for platforms where `sizeof(int) != 4`

Comment: `((-1)>>1) < 0` is not limited to "negative number is sign filling or 0 filling".  At PP time, this is `intmax_t` math, although reasonable to assume `int` math works likewise.  If one is trying to form highly portable code, `0x1F` and `0x1C` fail for non-32-bit `int` widths.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `_Static_assert (sizeof(int) == 4, "FATAL ERROR!!!! sizeof(int) IS NOT 4!!!!")`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Or alternatively those could be replaced with `(sizeof(int)<<3)-1` and `(sizeof(int)<<3)-4` respectively

Comment: `sizeof (int) << 3`?  That's significantly less portable than `sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT`, which is what I think you meant.

Comment: Why embed a requirement like that (and so rudely) when there's absolutely no need to?  (and a `char` and a byte aren't necessarily the same thing!)

Comment: @TobySpeight In C a char is the same as a 1 byte integer, hence `unsigned char` and `signed char`

Comment: Oops, I see newer C standards define "byte" to mean the same as "char" (section 3.6).  Thanks for the correction.